# checkServerTrusted как проверить сервер?

Tags: android, https, ssl

Делаю приложение для общения с сервером по htpps, на сервере имеется сертификат.
 Как мне настроить защищенное соединение проверив сертификат сервера в данном классе?

```
public class CustomTrustManager implements X509TrustManager {

@Override
public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain, String authType)
        throws CertificateException {}
@Override
public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain, String authType)
        throws CertificateException {}
@Override
public X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers()
{
    return null;
}
```

}